# Index out of Range - 9223372036854775807 - Swift 3

Tags: indexing, swift3, tableview, ios10, indexoutofrangeexception

I have an array of strings with locations that are displayed in a table, and when the user selects the table cell, that location gets added to another array. I want to display the selected locations in a label through that second array. But, when I select too many locations or one that is farther down the list, I get this error:

fatal error: Index out of range

The index number for all of the locations when I select each of them is 9223372036854775807. How do I get my code to recognize an index number for each location?

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableLocations: UITableView!
let itemsLocations: [String] = ["Pacific Northwest", "West Coast", "The West", "Midwest", "Great Lakes", "The South", "New England"]
var locationsPreviewtext = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsLocations.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellLoco: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellLocations")!
    cellLoco.textLabel?.text = itemsLocations[indexPath.row]
    return cellLoco
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    locationsPreviewtext.append(itemsLocations[indexPath.row]) //I get the error here when I select
    labelLocationsPreview.text = "\(locationsPreviewtext)"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if locationsPreviewtext.isEmpty {
        return
    }
    else {
        let ind = index(ofAccessibilityElement: locationsPreviewtext[indexPath.row]) //I get the error here when I deselect
        if ind == NSNotFound {
            locationsPreviewtext.remove(at: ind)
        }
        labelLocationsPreview.text = "\(locationsPreviewtext)"
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var labelLocationsPreview: UILabel!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destDetails: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
    destDetails.labelGifteeLocationsPreview.text = "\(locationsPreviewtext)"
}
```

Comment: We don't see your code, how could we possibly answer your question?

Comment: Question is edited. Thank you for being willing to help.

Comment: Your ```locationsPreviewtext``` does not have the same index as ```itemsLoactions``` because of the way you construct it. Your error is occurring on the ```didDeselectRowAt``` method.

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about fixing that? I am extremely new to Swift.